# PHP/Smarty - Each file has it own language file

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to get each file to have it own language file.

I am using a mix of osDate, SMF and my own code. osDate stores the language in the database, but I am not wanting this, I would like each file to have it own language file, so for example register has it own language file at lang/english/register.php.

I will be using Smarty, which is causing me the headache.

I have the below PHP code working, but don't know how to add or get the language side working.

Here is my current code.

**tester1.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('SMARTY_DIR')) {
    include_once('init_test.php');
}

$actionArray = array(
    'register' => array('Register.php', 'Register'),
);

if (!isset($_REQUEST['action']) || !isset($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']])) {
    echo '<a href="?action=register">test</a>';
} else {
    require_once($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][0]);
    call_user_func($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1]);

}

$t->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php

function Register() {
    global $t;
    $t->assign('rendered_page', $t->fetch('register.tpl'));
}

?>
```

**index.tpl**

```
{$rendered_page}
```

**register.tpl**

```
Test: {$testlang}<br>
Title: {$title}
```

**Language file - lang/english/register.php**

```
<?php

$lang['testlang'] = 'working';
$lang['title'] = 'This is the title';

?>
```

So in the example Register needs to pass the language from Register.php to display in register.tpl.

I am aware I can assign each language string in the Register.php file, but I was hoping, I would be able to just assign the who register language file and then just call it at random, without having to assign each language string in Register.php

Any code, tips welcome.
I have tried Googling, but it hasn't come up with much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass rendered things into Smarty - you should be passing in an array of strings to use.

**register.php**

```
$lang = array(
    'test' => "working",
    'title' => "This is the title", 
);

function Register() {
   global $lang;
   $t->assign('lang', $lang);
}
```

**index.tpl**

```
Test: {$lang['test']}<br>
Title: {$lang['title']}
```

Will do what you asked.

However - you don't want to code it like this as it will be incredibly painful to use when you inevitably need to pass in parameters to the strings.

You should define a [Smarty function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl) to display translated text with as many variables as needed e.g.

```
{translate string='Greeting' name=$user.name}
```

Where the translate function would pull the 'Greeting' string from the list of known strings which would be defined as `Hello %name%`. It would then replace `%name%` with the users name to say `Hello John` etc.